# What is the logic behind claiming the world is an appearance in brahman/atman/Self in advaita vedanta?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, advaita, spirituality, knowledge

Advaita Vedanta claims that we are consciousness and this world is an appearance in consciousness. I understand that we are consciousness but I don't understand how this world is an appearance in consciousness.

I have tried contemplating on it myself but I can neither claim that the world is different from consciousness nor that the world is an appearance in consciousness with 100% surety. For me both the possibilities are currently open.

As per my current understanding, I understand that I am consciousness and the observable universe that I am observing can not be the absolute reality but what it truly is I don't know whether its me(consciousness) or something apart from me.

Can anyone explain the logic behind oneness in advaita vedanta or refer me to some text, video, etc where the logic behind this is explained?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum is not meant to be opinions on videos. A link to a video is not a question.

Comment: I have modified the question to not refer to any person or video. I hope it's okay now.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, I think you've fixed it. I hope someone finds an answer for you.

Comment: Assuming by your Qn quality, you know nothing about the philosophy of Advaita.I suggest you first read some books introduction to Sanatana Dharma first, get a basic overview, then read a bit about some of the philosophies based on Vedanta, get familiar with the basic terminologies in Sanskrit that our Great Acharyas use to explain their philosophies, how they differ or all similar etc, then research a bit on this website for Qns that might arise and doubts(i am pretty sure this has been asked before multiple times), if then any doubt persists, present your research & then ask specific doubts!